# What is the "google-xrawler" user agent used for?

Tags: googlebot, user-agent

I'm getting over 100 requests per day from user agent `google-xrawler`. The requests are all for the same page. Some of the IP addresses are known to be Google IPs, although they don't have valid reverse DNS records.

What is this user agent used for?

Comment: He is right - [Nothing about it on the entire Internet](https://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/4604177.htm)

Comment: Already found and read that thread. Nothing in it says anything about what this user-agent is or does, other than suggesting it might be Google translate, but no one is going to translate the same page, only one page, and 100 times per day every day.

Comment: "I'm getting over 100 requests" - _requests_ or _page views_?

Comment: @DocRoot: They are entries in the Nginx access log. They are usually in pairs of  HEAD/GET requests.

Comment: Is it send request only to your feed page?

Answer (score 2):

Google requests product feed using the user agent "google-xrawler"

Comment: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Shopping-and-Merchant/Product-feed-Google-bot-change/td-p/426954